# How to make nginx proxy everything for a specific location instead of redirect?

Tags: nginx

Here is the nginx conf

```
  location /apis/ {
    proxy_pass http://todo-backend:8000/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```

Nginx has no problem proxying this API `http://localhost:4000/apis/todos/`, but redirecting `http://localhost:4000/apis/todos/24/` to `http://localhost/todos/24`
[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer: At the frontend, I include a trailing slash making api call, but my backend does not have it so it redirects. Fixing either frontend or backend to include/exclude the trailing slash.

Comment: The todo-backend is generating the redirect, not Nginx. You can configure Nginx to change the value of the `Location` response header using [the `proxy_redirect` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It gave me the right direction to look at. Apparently, at the frontend, I include a trailing slash making api call, but my backend does not have it so it redirects.